# How to call the method in Java clicking on a link?

Tags: java

This is my servlet:

```
   @WebServlet({ "/Response", "/reportsto" })
  public class Response extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Response() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    services2   messageservice = new services2();
    services3      jiraservice = new services3();
    service4            empid = new service4();
    String id = request.getParameter("ManagerId");

    try {

        String name="";
        String id1 =empid.getEmpId(id);
        System.out.println("id is ===> "+id1);
        Map<Object, Object> map=messageservice.getReportees(id1);
        Set<Map.Entry<Object,Object>> s1=map.entrySet();
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Object,Object>> iterator = s1.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)  {
            Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry = iterator.next();
            Object name1 = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
                    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
                    out.println("<html><body><table>\r\n" + 
                            "<tr>\r\n" + 
                            "<th>User Id</th>\r\n" + 
                            "<th>Username</th>\r\n" + 
                            "</tr>\r\n" + 
                            "<tr>\r\n" + 
                            "<td>"+value+"</td>\r\n" + 
                            "<td><a href=''>"+name1+"</a></td>\r\n" + 
                            "</tr>\r\n" + 
                            "</table></body></html>");
 //how should I pass the object value to getJiras which   accepts the strings.   
                }
    I will get the output as:
      User Id   Username
      AR12345   Anagha R
```

So If I click on Anagha the userid must be passed to the getJiras which has return type as Map Object and then It should process and display the 
CHA-3603: Validating Release on the browser in the same page of the above output.

```
 getJiras()

   public class services3{ 
   public Map<Object, Object> getJiras(String values) throws Exception {
        String api = "https:*****";
        String id  = values;
        String ext= "******";
        String url = api+id+ext;
        String name = "******";
        String password = "********";
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
        Client restClient = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);
        ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept("application/json")
                                         .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
                                         .get(ClientResponse.class);
        if(resp.getStatus() != 200){
            System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
        }
      //here I am trying to parse the json data.
        JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)parse.parse(output);
        JSONArray jsonarr_1 = (JSONArray) jobj.get("issues");
        System.out.println("The total number of issues in validating release   are:"+jsonarr_1.size());

        Map<Object, Object> map=new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        for(int i=0;i<jsonarr_1.size();i++){
            JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject)jsonarr_1.get(i);
            JSONObject jsonobj_2 = (JSONObject)jsonobj_1.get("fields");
            JSONObject status1   = (JSONObject)jsonobj_2.get("status");
            JSONObject issuetype = (JSONObject)jsonobj_2.get("issuetype");

            Object obj1         =  jsonobj_1.get("key");
            Object obj2         =  status1.get("name");

            map.put(obj1, obj2);
        }
        return  map;
    }
```

Also how can I also display the json array size which is being printed in the browser.The problem is getting complicated day by day,Please help to solve this problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: May I suggest to have a look at [Spring MVC](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-tutorial) architecture and Spring Boot. Writing hardcore servlets like you do is possible, but is much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another servlet or use same servlet to make one more `get` request. That request will call to `jira service`.

Case 1: Create another servlet, it is similar to what you are doing 
Case 2: You can custom your current servlet method `doGet`. Sample code is below.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  String requestAction = request.get("action");
  if("detail".equals(requestAction)) {
    services3 service = new services3();
     //get result.
  } else if("view".equals(requestAction)){
   //your current code
  }
  //add result to response
}
```

Comment: hey if we create another servlet how can we pass the value parameter to another servlet which inturn call the jira service

Comment: @RAMYA, you can use web.xml to configure multiple servlet. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559372/how-to-modify-web-xml-for-multiple-servlet

Comment: Suppose I have another servlet by name servlet2 now how should I pass the value parameter(dynamically changes) from servlet1 in href tag